# Access parent function if childs attribute is overwritten

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I fear that I am dump as hell, but I do not have a clue how to execute a methode from a class if the variable name is overwritten in the class instance.

```
class foo():
    def do_stuff(self, name):
        self.new = name

inst = foo()
inst.do_stuff("Hello")
inst.do_stuff = 19
```

This is the starting position. While the thing is running, a variable `do_suff` is declarated in `inst` so the function gets overwritten. My problem is, how do I manage that the method is called rather than the variable if I want to change variable `new` of `inst`?

I thought `super()` is the way to go, but I have no idea how to achieve this properly. Unforunately my english is not that good so I may screwed up asking search the correct questions.

Comment: How did you try to use `super`, and in what way didn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have a parent and a child, you have an instance of a class, super is used when you overwite a method of a base class

[super](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=super#super)

Answer (score 2):

Why would you have to overwrite the attribute `do_stuff`? You shouldn't do that.

```
foo.do_stuff(inst)
```

Comment: My example was pretty bad, I see now. What I want to do is writing something like a "database" where "Table" inherits from dict so I can create new tables by foo["table1"] = Table().

My problem is if there is a new table with the same name as a already existing function, I think I need to call the function via super().